# How to remove item from Recycleview from activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have recycleview where I implemented the search features. and each item has onClick added which removes items from list by below code.

```html
   holder.del_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                            int newPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                contactListFiltered.remove(newPosition);
                notifyItemRemoved(newPosition);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(newPosition, contactListFiltered.size());
});
```

It works fine with normal list but when any item is searched then on filtered results onclick listener deletes randomly may due to overlap of views.
So I pass the onclick listener to activity with below code

```html
            mSolved.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // send selected contact in callback
                    listener.onSolved(contactListFiltered.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                }
            });
            
             public interface FRoomAdapterListener {
        void onSolved(Districtpost contact);
    }
```

and in activity I am using

```html
    public void onDelete(Districtpost contact) {
            int newPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        contactListFiltered.remove(newPosition);
        notifyItemRemoved(newPosition);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(newPosition, contactListFiltered.size());
        
        });
```

which is certain to throw errors. How can I solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you dont have to follow `notifyItemRemoved` with `notifyItemRangeChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void onDelete(Districtpost contact) {
if(contactListFiltered != null && contactListFiltered.size > 0){
contactListFiltered.remove(contact);
notifydatasetchanged();
}});
```

Comment: contactlistFiltered is arraylist of filtered result in adapter, How do I pass it to activity?

Comment: past this function in adapter and call adapter.onDelete(contact) from activity dear

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourList.remove(position); //Remove item from list
notifyItemRemoved(position); //notify changes made to the adapter.
```